# Where is air inlet to draw air when AC is in re-circulation mode?

Tags: ac, air-intake

When we put the AC in re-circulation mode. It is supposed to draw the air from cabin, send it to AC for cooling and then throw it out of Vents. But where is in air-intake in this mode to draw air from cabin?

I am assuming the design would be almost similar in most cars. Let's face it every company copies best design from others.

Answer (score 1):

That intake is under the dash as that is where the choice between recirc or fresh air is made.